# Conf/Messages Choice in Play! + Scala

Tags: html, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I run the sample code in play 2.2 "comuputer-database-jpa"

In the `Conf/Messages`

```
# Messages

computers.list.title={0,choice,0#No computers|1#One computer|1<{0,number,integer} computers} found
```

I want to used this conditional messages in my error messages to make my error message as dynamic as possible. In my code say that i'm passing 2 parameters and 1 of it is the message id.

```
@Messages(messageId,errors(1).getOrElse(""),errors(2).getOrElse(""))
```

equivalent to

```
@Messages(error.format,FIRST NAME)
```

can also be

```
@Messages(error.format,EMAIL)
```

How can i use the conditional conf/messages in my code?  I tried some using the sample and an error occurred.
Code:

```
error.format = Enter {0,choice,FIRST NAME#{0} in half-width alphanumeric|EMAIL#{0} in valid format.}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will yield what you are looking for

```
//html<br/>
@Messages("error.format",2, "name error","email error")
```

Number **2** in the example above will show the message "EMAIL in valid format". if you change it to **1** it will show the message "FIRST NAME in half-width alphanumeric"

```
//messages<br/>
error.format = Enter {0,choice,1#FIRST NAME in half-width alphanumeric|2#EMAIL in valid format.}
```

Comment: Please format the answer correctly. Furthermore please have a look at [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).